# Use mvc razor DropDownList with bootstrap to accomplish a specific design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have created a DropDownList using MVC Razor and bootstrap, the dropdownlist shows values from a database and works fine but the design is very simple

[image]

and here is the code:

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-10">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Seleccione</span>
    @Html.DropDownList("algo", ViewBag.ddl as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })    
</div>
```

but I really would like to use this design:

[image]

for the moment I've tried adding button this way:

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-10">
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1">Select</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    @Html.DropDownList("algo", ViewBag.ddl as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

but the result is the next one:

[image]

could you please tell if there is a way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using some css

```css
<style>
 select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

</style>
<body>

<h3>Using CSS </h3>

<div>
<label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```